# How to display “where value is in dynamic list” in HQL/GORM? (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, grails, hql, grails-orm

I am using MongoDB with GORM.
In the shopping cart, i have stored product id in MongoDB and want corresponding product details which are stored in MySQL.

When i look for product ID, i am able to display them individually.
def cart = u.Mycart
println cart[0]

It is an array list.
how can i get all elements together and query that list in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a good fit for [`getAll`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getAll.html), if productId is the identifier.

Comment: I don't think they are. :) method names are self explanatory.